# Checking if email exists in SQL database dynamically on blur?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, wordpress

I am writing a Wordpress PHP form which creates database entries with the submissions. I would like to dynamically check if the email address, a user has entered into the form, is already in the database or not.

Currently, the check happens on submit of the form, but I would like for it to happen dynamically after the user tabs out of the email field and I am not sure how to accomplish this. I am assuming I will need to use AJAX or similar.

Here is the code from my form page:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/inc/form.php" method="post">
    <label for="first_name">First Name: <span>(required)</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />

    <label for="last_name">Last Name: <span>(required)</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />

    <label for="email">Email: <span>(required)</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="email">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the part of the code from my form.php file which checks for duplicate entries:

```
$dupQuery = $wpdb->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");

if ($dupQuery != 0) {
    print "Email already exists";
} else {
    //store entry in database
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: That query is subject to a SQL injection attack as it is currently written. See [this warning from Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Running_General_Queries) on the use of this object.

Comment: @Todd, thank you for pointing that out. I plan on looking into security at a later date, but this form is only going to be used on an internal network at work, so currently I am not too concerned about it.

Comment: Yes you need ajax. However, implementing ajax in WordPress and the javascript code combined make this a very broad question. You should start looking on how to implement ajax in WP and take it from there. You could take a look here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a new page that does the db lookup (look in the Ajax code down at the bottom where it's referencing a fictitious page `/whatever/directory/lookup_page.php`). This page will reference that page, so that page has to exist or this won't work. You would probably want to figure a way to disable the submit button with jQuery if the email returns true. If the email is not in the db, then your submit button would stay active and the user would click submit when done. Anyway hopefully this helps at the very least to understand the Ajax. Also, I did keyup instead of blur so it does key by key lookup. You could change that though.

```
<form action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/inc/form.php" method="post">
    <label for="first_name">First Name: <span>(required)</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />

    <label for="last_name">Last Name: <span>(required)</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />

    <label for="email">Email: <span>(required)</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onKeyUp="AjaxLookup()">
    <div id="emailchecker"></div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

     function AjaxLookup() {
             var emAddr = $('#email').val();

             $.ajax({
                     url:"/whatever/directory/lookup_page.php?email="+emAddr,
                     success:function(result) {
                         $("#emailchecker").html(result);
                    }
                 });
            }
 </script>
```